# TYPO3, realurl not working after change the domain

Tags: php, typo3, realurl, typo3-4.7

We have an old TYPO3 site (v4.7) and we moved the site to another domain.
now all the pages give the error: 404 Not Found

when I tried to get the page using URLs containing page id like `/index.php?id=2`, it works

how can I fix the site to works using real spoken URL `/page-name`

thanks

Comment: What the server are you using?

Comment: please check .htaccess file in is present in your folder or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should change the domain record (in the backend, at the root of the domain in "List" view).

Maybe the domain is hard-coded in your realurl-config which is usually at /typo3conf/realurl* (realurl-extension configuration in the extension manager). If you selected "auto-configuration" in realurl's extension configuration and nobody made the mistake to make changes to the file directly, you can delete it and let it regenerate.

Maybe TypoScript settings like config.baseURL or config.absRefPrefix have a say here, too. I suggest to check in the template analyzer (backend: "Template" -> select your domain's root -> template analyzer -> view complete listing) if there is something with the old domain.

Of course, realurl needs to be activated (TypoScript config.tx_realurl_enable = 1) but if you did not change it, that should not have changed.

Then of course clear all caches (preferably via the function in the Install Tool).

If you still have problems, deleting /typo3temp (and recreating it via the InstallTool) might help. And check if there's something useful in the logs, of course (where, depends on ['SYS']['systemLog'] and ['SYS']['systemLogLevel'], probably typo3temp/*.log or your PHP error log).

Good luck with that ole' T3 ;)

Comment: And you should check, if the .htaccess file is in the document root directory.